# What is the difference between Cargo's environment variables RUSTC and RUSTC_WRAPPER?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Cargo's environment variables are explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html).

- `RUSTC` - Instead of running `rustc`, Cargo will execute this specified compiler instead.
- `RUSTC_WRAPPER` - Instead of simply running `rustc`, Cargo will execute this specified wrapper instead, passing as its commandline arguments the `rustc` invocation, with the first argument being `rustc`.

`RUSTC` and `RUSTC_WRAPPER` variables look like they are doing the same thing. How are they different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation states:

- If `RUSTC` is defined, Cargo will not execute this line:

  ```
  rustc <parameters>
  ```

  but this one:

  ```
  $RUSTC <parameters>
  ```

  That is like the variable `CC` in Makefiles to set an alternative compiler.
- If `RUSTC_WRAPPER` is defined, Cargo will not call the compiler itself. It will instead call the following line:

  ```
  $RUSTC_WRAPPER rustc <parameters>
  ```

  You can add the options you want, or do whatever you want before the compilation, but you have to call the compiler yourself. Well, that's the purpose of a wrapper.